# Repaint() method causes UI to flash and flicker

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint

So I have been coding this little UI for a while and for some reason the repaint() method seems to cause the image generated on the screen to flicker and flash. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Timer;

public class userInterfaceSimple extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{   
    static ArrayList<Creature> list = new ArrayList<Creature>();
    static JButton next = new JButton("Begin");
    static Timer timer = new Timer();
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final static JPanel pane = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        new userInterfaceSimple();
    }

    public userInterfaceSimple()
    {
        super("Toy Planet: Life, a Simulation");

        setSize(1000,1000);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                 if(next.getText().equals("Begin"))
                 {
                    next.setText("Stop");
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            checkRules();
                            repaint();  
                        }
                    }, 250, 250);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    next.setText("Begin");
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = new Timer();
                 }
            }
        });

        add(next, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j ++)
        {
            Creature orgArc = new Creature();
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                 list.add(new Creature(orgArc.gene));   
            }
        }   
        sortList();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            g.setColor(list.get(i).getColor());
            int size = list.get(i).getSize();
            g.fillOval(list.get(i).getX() - size/2, list.get(i).getY() - size/2,size,size);
        }

    }

    public static void checkRules()
    {   
        int size = list.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    boolean alreadyMoved = false;
                    if(!(list.get(i)).equals(list.get(j)))
                    {

                        int x = list.get(j).getX() - (list.get(i)).getX();
                        int y = list.get(j).getY() - (list.get(i)).getY();
                        double z = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);

                        //Passive Interaction Rules
                        //Sight Check
                        if(list.get(j).getSense() > z)
                        {
                            list.get(j).moveTo(list.get(i));
                            alreadyMoved = true;
                        }

                        if(z <= 1.5)
                        {
                            //Active Interaction Rules
                            //Breeding Check
                            if(list.get(j).isCompatible(list.get(i))) 
                            {
                                list.add(list.get(j).breed(list.get(i)));
                                sortList();
                            }
                            //Eating Check
                            else if(list.get(j).getAggro() > 15 || list.get(j).getDiet() > 3) 
                            {
                                list.get(j).eat(list.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //If no checks fire then move randomly
                    if(alreadyMoved == false)
                    {
                        Organism temp = new Organism();
                        list.get(j).moveTo(temp);           
                    }
                }
                //Hunger Check
                list.get(i).hungerCheck();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

            list.get(i).validate();
            size = size - validateList();
        }  
        /*for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++) //for debugging.
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).getInfo());
        }
        System.out.println("----");*/
    }

    public static int getClosestCreature(Organism org)
    {
        int x,y;
        double z;
        double tempZ = 100000;
        int closest = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!(list.get(i)).equals(org))
            {
                x = org.getX() - (list.get(i)).getX();
                y = org.getY() - (list.get(i)).getY();
                z = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
                if(z < tempZ)
                {
                    closest = i;
                    tempZ = z;
                }
            }       
        }
        return (closest);
    }

    public static int validateList()
    {
        int netLoss = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if((list.get(i)).getAlive() == false)
            {
                list.remove(i);
                netLoss = netLoss + 1;
            }  
        }   
        return netLoss;
    }

    public static void sortList()
    {
        Creature temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < list.size() - i; j++)
            {
                if(list.get(j - 1).getSpeed() > list.get(j).getSpeed())
                {
                    temp = list.get(j - 1);
                    list.set(j - 1, list.get(j));
                    list.set(j, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is simple: Double Buffering should fix it. For more reference, visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html

First you should create `private BufferedImage bufferImage;`
In your `public void paint(Graphics g)` you should paint stuff into this bufferImage, and then, when bufferImage is filled, paint it `g.drawImage(bufferImage, 0, 0, null);`

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   Graphics2D gr = bufferImage.createGraphics();
   for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
       {
           gr.setColor(list.get(i).getColor());
           int size = list.get(i).getSize();
           gr.fillOval(list.get(i).getX() - size/2, list.get(i).getY() - size/2,size,size);
       }
    super(g);
    g.drawImage(bufferImage, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Not compiled, but something like this should work.

Comment: This just causes a crash. But I will play around with this, cheers!

Comment: 1. idea about loop inside array of prepared Object is correcty v.s BufferedImage, but there no reason to play with  Double Buffering nor for JFrame, JPanel (with getPreferredSize) do that, 2. Swing TImer instead of whatever from java.util package